# How to fix all data saving to one column dataframe to csv

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am attempting to read a csv file and then save it in another location.

I have tried importing csv or string. I am realizing it only seems possible using Pandas. I have tried sep = ' ' and sep = '\s+' (this gives error) and I have tried a regex command from an earlier answered post ( I cant remember the exact command). So far sep = '\t' seems like it should work but it is not.

```
import pandas as pd

readfile = pd.read_csv('C:\\xx\\xx\\xx, xx.csv','rb')
with open('T:\\xx\\xx\\xx.csv','w') as writefile:
           readfile.to_csv(writefile, index = False, sep = '\t')
```

I expect the data to be exported in an excel file in multiple columns. I however, get all the data in 1 column when I open the excel file. If I print the variable readfile, using print(readfile) I get the following:

```
25    1 1 9 \t \t T w o - W i r e   O h m s \t 1   ...
26    1 2 0 \t \t T w o - W i r e   O h m s \t 1   ...
27    S c a n     C o n t r o l : \t S t a r t   A ...
28    S c a n \t T i m e \t 1 0 1   ( O H M ) \t A ...
29    1 \t 7 / 2 4 / 2 0 1 9   1 3 : 1 3 : 3 5 : 3 ...
..                                                 ...
72    4 4 \t 7 / 2 4 / 2 0 1 9   1 3 : 2 0 : 4 5 : ...
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some data from your CSV?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, select Data-> Text to Columns and then set the delimiter to tabs